# How to ignore errors when using executemany for SQLite insertions?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm inserting ~500k items into an sqlite database using Python's sqlite3 module and execute many, chunking up the inserts:

```
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    for chunk in (values[i:i+CHUNK_SIZE] for i in xrange(0, len(values), CHUNK_SIZE)):
        data = ((x[0], x[1].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) for x in chunk)
        try:
            c.executemany('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (?,?)', data )
            self.conn.commit()
        except Exception, e:
            print "EXCEPTION:", e, data
```

The data is not in my control and sometimes contains bad encodings, causing errors in the executemany:

```
You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can 
interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended 
that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

I've tried various ways of decoding the text but the errors keep coming back.

I'd like to ignore the errors, skipping the items with the encoding problems (or store them partially; doesn't really matter) while storing the rest.

Is there a way to tell executemany to not bail out on inserting the rest of the batch when it runs into an error? executemany that ignores errors but stores the rest of the items?

Comment: Similar problem here (integrity). Too bad it probably has no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

It would seem simplest to filter the `data` for each `chunk`; i.e, instead of:

```
data = ((x[0], x[1].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) for x in chunk)
```

something like:

```
data = []
for x in chunk:
    try: second = x[1].decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError: continue
    data.append((x[0], second))
```

This should have exactly the desired effect when this cleaned-up `data` is passed to `executemany`-- so that you're "skipping lines with encoding problems" (assuming the latter come from the second item; if the issue's with `x[0]` then that needs to be checked, too).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I don't think I get an exception during the decode part (it's a bit hard to verify as the item with the error is hidden in the 500k items), but I'll give this a try.

Comment: with `'ignore'` as the second argument, ypu shouldn't be getting any exception in `decode`; that's why I removed it in my snippet:-).